# Multiple keys multiple values

Tags: python, excel, dictionary

I am trying to make a dictionary `details` with 3 keys `Username`, `Password`, `Emailid` which would contain multiple values each. I am trying to add the values for the keys from an Excel workbook.

I want to access each particular value for the dictionary say

```
details{"Username":Value1,"Password":Value1,"Emailid":Value1}
```

And so on.

**updated the code now

i tried to read and store the values of keys and their corresponding data from excel itself.this is the update code

```
    import openpyxl
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('user_details.xlsx')
    WSheet = get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    # get the active working sheet 1
       print('Reading rows...')
       # read header values into the list    
       keys = [sheet.cell(0, col_index).value for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)]
print "keys are", keys
dict_list = []
for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows):
    assetData= {keys[col_index]: sheet.cell(row_index, col_index).value 
         for col_index in xrange(sheet.ncols)}
    dict_list.append(d)
print dict_list

Trying to print the value
for k,v in assetData.items():
    Print(%s "hi  %s  ,Records show that you have not paid dues " %  (+ str(assetData[assettagtype["k"]]) +str(assetData[assettagname["k"]]))
    # this line of code is just an idea ,syntactically incorrect
```

Sample data:

```
username    password    emailid
A123    alpha   abc@xyz.com
b123    tango   pqr@xyz.com
c123    charlie muv@xyz.com
```

Comment: i tried to read and store the values of keys and their corresponding data from excel itself.this is the update code

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what your looking for, but going by what you said here:

> I want to access each particular value for the dictionary

I'm guessing you want to iterate the dictionary and get each value.  To do that, you would use `dict.items()` syntax:

```
for key, value in details.items():
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(key, value))
```

And if you just need the values, you would use `dict.values()`:

```
for value in details.values():
    print(value)
```

Comment: yes indeed i would like to iterate the print statement to print the "hi remember your password and email" statement for all values in the dictionary..would this work for keys with multiple values?...like i said username,password,emailid will all have different values which i would like to access once at a time.

Comment: Yes it would work with keys that have multiple values (ie. ``list`` of items)